# Bad characters in Return Oriented Programming

Tags: exploit, aslr, dep

I am writing a rop chain for a vulnerable program (stack overflow, with NX and ASLR turned on).

I follow the execution of my gadgets by watching the stack pointer on gdb peda. It works well except when it encounters a gadget `mov[eax], edx; ret`. This gadget gets executed, but after there is a `push ebx` that follows, even if I didn't put any gadget like that in my ROP chain. And in the end my exploit doesn't work.

I have tried with different registers this instruction and there is always the `push ebx` that follows and I don't know why.

Would someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Program is not always vulnerable under NX and ASLR enabled conditions.

In the most of time, you can't find enough gadget to produce your ROP exploit.

Maybe you could take a look of [ROPgadget](https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/ROPgadget).

This tool could help you to find useful gadget to assemble ROP exploit.